# i want to assign a snapshot.val() to to $scope variable $scope.pending and bind it to a ng-repeat list

Tags: angularjs, firebase

```
     firebase  logged data

Object {information: "way", status: "pending", title: "killa"}
controllers.js:43 Object {information: "way", status: "pending", title: "killa"}
controllers.js:42 Object {information: "way", status: "pending", title: "killa2"}
controllers.js:43 Object {information: "way", status: "pending", title: "killa2"}
```

i dont seem to get the list of items im fetching from firebase but im able to log it.

```
<ion-list  ng-controller="pendingTasksCtrl">
              <ion-item ng-click="task.completed = !task.completed" class="item-icon-right"  ng-repeat="p in pending">{{p.title}}{{p.information}}
                <i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-left"></i>
                <ion-option-button class="ion-trash-a" ng-click="removeItem($index,1)">
                </ion-option-button>
                 <ion-option-button ng-controller="editTaskCtrl" class="ion-edit" ng-click="modal.show()">
                 </ion-option-button>
               </ion-item>
                </ion-list>
```

i want to assign snapshot to a $scope.pending and bind it on front end. but im getting an undefined error

```
.controller('pendingTasksCtrl', function($scope,$firebaseArray,$firebaseObject,$rootScope,$ionicModal)
{

  var task = "AllTasks";
  var id =0;

            var itemref = new Firebase("https://tasksbylima.firebaseio.com/");
            //$scope.items = $firebaseArray(itemref);
            //var status = "completed";

            $scope.test = function()
            {
            itemref.orderByChild("status").equalTo("pending").on("child_added", function(snapshot)
             {
               $scope.pending = snapshot.val();

                console.log(snapshot.val());
                console.log(pending);

          //  console.log("**************find me "+itemref.orderByChild("status").equalTo("task").on("child_added"));
          });

}
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var itemref = new Firebase("https://tasksbylima.firebaseio.com/task");
   var taskref = itemref.orderByChild("status").equalTo(true);
     taskref.on("value", function(response) {
     $scope.filterTasks = response.val();
```

That works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You are testing `console.log(pending)`, but it should be `console.log($scope.pending)`. `pending` is undefined because you don't have any separate variable with that name.

**Edit**

According to your comment, I guess you are loosing a reference to the array then. When you use `=` to replace your current data in `$scope`, you are assiging a new array and view has still a reference to the first one. I see two possible solutions:

*Solution 1*

Wrap your array with an object.

```
$scope.model = {
    pending: []
}
```

In view: change `pending` to `model.pending`.

In controller: use `$scope.model.pending` instead of `$scope.pending`. This way a reference to the array will not change as it's a property of an object.

*Solution 2*

Instead of using `=` use `splice` and `for`.

At the beginning of the controller add array initialization:

```
$scope.pending = [];
```

Then, change `$scope.pending = snapshot.val()` to:

```
var data = snapshot.val();
$scope.pending.splice(0)  // this will empty the array 

// This will insert new elements
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    $scope.pending.push(data[i]);
}
```

Comment: thanks... but the whole idea is bind this on the front end. ng-repeat list

Comment: Cannot read property 'splice' of undefined. thats the error im getting there. im new to angular the solution is not clear to me

Comment: At the beginning of the controller add `$scope.pending = []`. The array must be initialized in order to use splice on it. It's rather matter of JavaScript than AngularJS itself - splice is javascript arrays' built-in function

Comment: this returns an empty array.

Comment: do i still bind this in this manner ng-repeat="p in pending" {{p.title}} {{p.information}}  ?

Comment: how to i call this from the ng-repeat

Comment: Yes, if you are still assigning data to a `$scope` property called `pending`, then binding in the view will not change

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Firebase and Angular 2. The problem with `.on` functions is that they somehow loose connection to `this` in Angular 2, in AngularJS I imagine that there might be a similar problem with `$scope`.

Try this:

```
  itemref.orderByChild("status").equalTo("pending").on("child_added", function(snapshot)
         {
           $scope.pending = snapshot.val();

            console.log(snapshot.val());
            console.log($scope.pending);
      }.bind($scope));
```

Now it should be available in your HTML/Frontend.

Comment: Problems with `this` are something different. As you say, reference to `this` is lost, because functions are creating own context (which is kept in`this`). Solution is to use `bind` or create a `self` variable like `var self = this` at the beginning. However, it should only affect `this` - not any other property. `$scope` is just an object passed as parameter to the controller function. Another thing is that `bind` function only specifies, what will be bound to `this` inside function.

Comment: i get that, if able to log the data, whats preventing it from being binded on the front end.

Comment: thanks @PJDev for clarifying! I'm currently binding to every `.on` function this which works as you explained. Do you know what's recommended?

Comment: I'm used to `var self = this` or `var that = this`, but honestly I don't know if it's better than `.bind(this)`. Maybe there are other, better methods. I will investigate it in the near future, but for now I cannot tell it as I'm still learning JS. Fortunately, there are many discussions on this topic, so someone must have provided a clear answer :)